# CommandLink in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, commandlink

Can someone tell me how can I add a CommandLink control in a WPF window?

This is what I mean by CommandLink : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511455.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WPF Task Dialog Wrapper](https://github.com/yadyn/WPF-Task-Dialog) provides an implementation of a [`CommandLink`](https://github.com/yadyn/WPF-Task-Dialog/blob/master/TaskDialog/CommandLink.xaml) user control.

Here's an example of how to show command links:

```
TaskDialogOptions config = new TaskDialogOptions();

config.Owner = this;
config.Title = "RadioBox Title";
config.MainInstruction = "The main instruction text for the TaskDialog goes here.";
config.Content = "The content text for the task dialog is shown here "
               + "and the text will automatically wrap as needed.";
config.ExpandedInfo = "Any expanded content text for the task dialog "

                    + "is shown here and the text will automatically wrap as needed.";
config.CommandButtons = new string[] {
    "Command &Link 1", "Command Link 2\nLine 2\nLine 3", "Command Link 3" };
config.MainIcon = VistaTaskDialogIcon.Information;

TaskDialogResult res = TaskDialog.Show(config);
```

[image: WPF Task Dialog Wrapper]

The library is licensed under the The Code Project Open License.

---

[Seven Update](https://github.com/sevenalive/SevenUpdate/) has another nice implementation of a [`CommandLink`](https://github.com/sevenalive/SevenUpdate/blob/master/Externals/SevenSoftware.Windows/Controls/CommandLink.cs) Button.

This is how it looks like:

[image: Seven Update]

Bear in mind that is a project licensed under the GPL v3 license.

---

This guide might help too:

[Creating Command Link Controls in Silverlight with Expression Blend 3 and Behaviors](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/ee662150)

Comment: Are there any less time consuming solutions without copyleft licence? ;)

Comment: @OneWorld I've updated my answer with another library. You can edit my answer (or add your one) if you find something else you think is useful or worth sharing :)

Comment: Thank you for your post. I imported the the library in my project. I could add the `<TaskDialog:CommandLink />` to my XAML, but now I have a hard time to adjust the text and icon to my needs. I also included the source project instead of the library in my project. But even then I can't get hold on the properties I need to adjust.