# Are there alternative message box results

Tags: .net, messagebox

I'm wondering if anyone has found a way for the `MessageBox.Show()` method to return anything other than the enum values passed to it.

It would be handy to have a way to detect alternate keystrokes. For example, <kbd>F10</kbd> key, even though `Show()` does not display it.

Comment: Yeah, the standard method is this: If you want custom messagebox behavior make your own form.

Comment: What MessageBox does got frozen in concrete 30 years ago.  Whatever you are looking for is *not* MessageBox, just make your own dialog.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way for .NET with a simple API as MessageBox.

However, there are alternatives to MessageBox, e.g. [CommandLink [Stack Overflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870314/commandlink-in-wpf) dialogs, which provide much better usability in many cases (if used right). You may also find such functionality in (commercial) 3rd party libraries.

If you can't find anything suitable online, just implement your own `Form` or `UserControl`. It's not that hard... If you like to handle custom key presses, that's probably what you need to do.